# Find objects whose nested objects match two different values for the same key

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have objects that look like this:

```json
[
  {
    "url": "a",
    "nested_object_keys": [
      {
        "vendor": "terraform",
        "tag": "some_tag"
      },
      {
        "vendor": "terraform",
        "tag": "some_other_tag"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "url": "c",
    "nested_object_keys": [
      {
        "vendor": "terraform",
        "tag": "some_tag"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "url": "b",
    "nested_object_keys": [
      {
        "vendor": "terraform",
        "tag": "some_tag"
      },
      {
        "vendor": "terraform",
        "tag": "some_other_tag"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to find objects whose nested object keys match `{'tag': 'some_tag'}` AND `{'tag': 'some_other_tag'}`.

I tried a few different ways (using `$elemMatch`) and the only one that works is:

```js
query = {
    '$and': [
        {
            'nested_object_keys': {
                '$elemMatch': {'tag': 'some_tag'}
            }
        },
        {
            'nested_object_keys': {
                '$elemMatch': {'tag': 'some_other_tag'}
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a more compact way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$all` operator:

```
db.collection.find({
  "nested_object_keys.tag": { $all: ["some_tag", "some_other_tag"] }
})
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aBo19ujB8dC)